# how to Filter on internal table using multiple fields

Tags: abap

My requirement is to filter internal table using multiple fields.

```
CONSTANTS:lc_star TYPE c VALUE '*'.

DATA: lit_x_all    TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ztt WITH NON-UNIQUE KEY extsystem ccode ekorg werks matkl,
      lit_filter_e TYPE SORTED TABLE OF ztt-extsystem WITH NON-UNIQUE KEY table_line,
      lit_filter_o TYPE SORTED TABLE OF ztt-ekorg WITH NON-UNIQUE KEY table_line,
      lit_filter_c TYPE SORTED TABLE OF ztt-ccode WITH NON-UNIQUE KEY table_line,
      lit_filter_w TYPE SORTED TABLE OF ztt-werks WITH NON-UNIQUE KEY table_line.

SELECT * 
      FROM ztt 
      WHERE a = @i_a
      INTO TABLE @lit_x_all.

LOOP AT i_pit_input INTO DATA(lwa_input).

  "filter to avoid select statement in loop

  lit_filter_e = VALUE #( ( CONV #( lc_star ) ) ( lwa_input-extsystem ) ).
  DATA(lit_final_e) = FILTER #( lit_approver_all IN lit_filter_e WHERE extsystem = table_line ).

  lit_filter_o = VALUE #( ( CONV #( lc_star ) ) ( lwa_input-ekorg ) ).
  DATA(lit_final_o) = FILTER #( lit_final_e IN lit_filter_o WHERE ekorg = table_line ).

  lit_filter_c = VALUE #( ( CONV #( lc_star ) ) ( lwa_input-ccode ) ).
  DATA(lit_final_c) = FILTER #( lit_final_o IN lit_filter_c WHERE ccode = table_line ).

  lit_filter_w = VALUE #( ( CONV #( lc_star ) ) ( lwa_input-werks ) ).
  DATA(lit_final_w) = FILTER #( lit_final_c IN lit_filter_w WHERE werks = table_line ).

ENDLOOP.
```

Currently I am using above code with filter for each field. Can we achieve same requirement with single filter instead of multiple filters?

Thanks
Phani

Comment: you code looks like nonsensity, give the sample input table and expected output

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abenconstructor_expression_filter.htm) states:

> Table filtering can also be performed using a table comprehension or a table reduction with an iteration expression for table iterations with FOR. The operator FILTER provides a shortened format for this special case and is more efficient to execute.

As in your case filtering with `FILTER` does not work as you're effectively ORing the 'star case' and 'filter value case', using the `VALUE` constructor to perform table comprehension is the better choice:

```
DATA(result) = VALUE #(
  FOR entry IN entries
    WHERE (
      ( a = '*' OR a = filter-a ) AND
      ( b = '*' OR b = filter-b )
      "...
    )
    ( entry )
).
```

This should also be by magnitutes faster as it avoids the creation of multiple intermediate internal tables.

Comment: Thanks for reply . In my case if i use FOR then it will become loop inside a loop . is it good to use inside loop.

Comment: So `FILTER` is not "a loop"? What is a loop from your perspective and why would nesting loops be bad?